# Vector Subscript out of range 3D vector

Tags: c++

I keep getting vector subscript out of range. I tried to figure out what is wrong, but failed. Can someone please help me out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   vector<vector<vector<double>>> kernelWindow;
   kernelWindow.resize(6, vector<vector<double>>(5, vector<double>(3,0)));
   for(int m = 0; m <= 6; m++){
            for(int n = 1; n <= 5-1; n++){
                kernelWindow[m][n][0] = 22;
                kernelWindow[m][n][1] = 32;
                kernelWindow[m][n][2] = 42;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace when it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
kernelWindow.resize(6, ...);
for(...; m <= 6; ...)
```

kernelWindow[6] doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies here:

```
for(int m = 0; m <= 6; m++){
```

`kernelWindow` has only 6 cells, ranging from 0 to 5, not 0 to 6.